# get count of files from a folder in u-sql to process

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-stream-analytics, azure-analytics

How to get count of files from a folder(directory) in u-sql

if the folder has more than one file then process only the latest file else process first file !!

Comment: This is possible when your files have same naming like File1, File2, File3, etc... So in that case you can try get it like ```/someFolder/File{0}.csv```.

Comment: can you pls elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments you can do something like this:

```cs
DECLARE EXTERNAL @input string = @"/someFolder/{file}.csv";

@extractedData = EXTRACT file as string,
                         col1 as number,
                         col2 as string
                         FROM @input
                         USING new Extractors.Csv();
```

So whit this you will extract all files in folder and use it, even if it is one file or multiple. **You need to guarantee that the files have same structure** or your extractor will throw an error like

> "expected 3 columns but got "x" columns...

After that you can work on your files data.

Comment: i want to know the count of files from a directory in u-sql. how can we achieve that in u-sql ?